# What is the logic behind token reflections?

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I've noticed that a lot of tokens that implement reflections come from safemoon. And I was curious about how safemoon did reflections. I expected to find a for loop somewhere where they are adding to each account's balance, but I did not find anything like that. Instead I foud _rOwned and _tOwned. I kept researching and I came across RFI the contract that started reflections (correct me if I am wrong). But even still I did not really understand how the accounts recieve more tokens? I found their reflect function. (in safemoon its called deliver)

```
    function deliver(uint256 tAmount) public {
        address sender = _msgSender();
        require(!_isExcluded[sender], "Excluded addresses cannot call this function");
        (uint256 rAmount,,,,,) = _getValues(tAmount);
        _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
        _rTotal = _rTotal.sub(rAmount);
        _tFeeTotal = _tFeeTotal.add(tAmount);
    }
```

But after finding this I only had more questions than anserws. Who is calling this function? Why is it not used anywhere in the source code? Another function I found that was just as confusing was reflectionFromToken()

```
    function reflectionFromToken(uint256 tAmount, bool deductTransferFee) public view returns(uint256) {
        require(tAmount <= _tTotal, "Amount must be less than supply");
        if (!deductTransferFee) {
            (uint256 rAmount,,,,,) = _getValues(tAmount);
            return rAmount;
        } else {
            (,uint256 rTransferAmount,,,,) = _getValues(tAmount);
            return rTransferAmount;
        }
    }
```

Once again where is the function being called? What is it even for? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also being studying the [Safemoon token's source code](https://github.com/safemoonprotocol/Safemoon.sol/blob/main/Safemoon.sol).

1. **deliver** function can only be called by non excluded addresses (contract's and contract owner's addresses), and implies a kind of token burning. I suppose is to be called by anyone who wants to "burn" tokens, especially for project team.

Look at these 2 lines of code in deliver function:

```
_rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
_rTotal = _rTotal.sub(rAmount);
```

Substract rAmount from sender's r balance and from rTotal (r supply).
From _getRValues functions:

```
rAmount = tAmount.mul(currentRate);
```

And **currentRate** is just rSupply/tSupply in most of cases (except for excluded addresses).

2. I'm not sure who call reflectionFromToken, but it's just a view function (it does not modify any value contract's state).
3. Take a look to **balanceOf** and **tokenFromReflection** functions to properly understand the reflection and how the fee sharing is done across all the addresses.

Each holder's balance in the current moment is calculated in this way:

```
function balanceOf(address account) public view override returns (uint256) {
    if (_isExcluded[account]) return _tOwned[account];
    return tokenFromReflection(_rOwned[account]);//=> rAmount/currentRate
}

function tokenFromReflection(uint256 rAmount) public view returns(uint256) {
    require(rAmount <= _rTotal, "Amount must be less than total reflections");
    uint256 currentRate =  _getRate();
    return rAmount.div(currentRate);
}
```